# Is it correct to write "offer of" or "offer on" and "whenever suits you better"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am replying to a job offer and I would like to thank the opportunity given.

I was going to begin my message with:

> "Thank you for the offer on CompanyName... "

As part of a response to a message with a job offer I would like to let them know:

> "I will be available all morning, so just call me whenever suits you
>   better"

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Offer of employment at -Company Name-
2. I will be available all morning. Please call me at your convenience.